# error: use of undeclared identifier 'LP_c_uint'

Tags: cppyy

I am using cppyy in my project to call C APIs.

I get below error log captured by capfd plugin in pytest, when an exception happens:

```
input_line_33:2:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LP_c_uint'
 (sizeof (LP_c_uint))
```

It is coming from below code block, specifically logger.error() call:

```
try:
....
except Exception as e:
    out, err = capfd.readouterr()
    if err:
        logger.error(err)
```

Now, if I grep my python source code, I don't any hits to 'LP_c_uint'.
Any pointers on how to debug this (like what may be causing this)?

### Edit:

simple reproducer:

```
from ctypes import c_uint32, pointer, byref
import cppyy

from cppyy import sizeof
cppyy.cppdef(
    """
    void func(uint32_t *param) {
        std::cout << "param: " << *param << std::endl;
    }
    """
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    param = pointer(c_uint32(17))
    cppyy.gbl.func(param)
    print(sizeof(param))
```

Output:

```
param: 17
input_line_22:2:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LP_c_uint'
 (sizeof (LP_c_uint))
          ^
0
```

Comment: You will have to post a reproducer: that first error message is from Cling, but `LP_c_uint` is the type of `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint)`. I have no idea how a `ctypes` type can have found its way into the C++ JIT.

Comment: Actually, here's an easy way to get that precise error: `cppyy.sizeof(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint))`. Probably something of that style happening in your code. To debug, it'd be helpful to get the full python stack instead of capturing the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have exactly the sequence you have mentioned present. Added small reproducer for the same.

Comment: There is `ctypes.sizeof` for use with ctypes' types. I'm not sure the reproducer tells the whole story: e.g. how did cppyy and ctypes types get mixed? cppyy accepts ctypes' types as function parameters, but I don't think it ever returns any.

Comment: okay, so story is, I have an C function which accepts a void * to a struct and its size. For usual cases, I would create the structure in python the usual way and pass it along with its size using cppyy.sizeof. But one particular instance is there, where instead of structure, I need to pass pointer to an integer. This is where, I see things get mixed up. and correct way here would be to use ctypes.sizeof instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using `ctypes.sizeof` would solve it. I see the need for using `ctypes.c_uint32` here (although using `ctypes.pointer` is not necessary) as there is no way of creating a pointer type from `cppyy.gbl.uint32_t` (which is basically Python's `int`, so internals to take a pointer to are not exposed).

`cppyy.sizeof` is now changed to forward to `ctypes.sizeof` as necessary. That'll make your code work and will be part of next release. As a current workaround, you can do something similar. For example:

```
def my_sizeof(tt):
    try:
        return ctypes.sizeof(tt)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    return cppyy.sizeof(tt)
```